# Is it good practice to keep file extension in a seperate table?

Tags: php, mysql, database-design

I am working on a ecommerce personal project. I am trying to change the structure of my db to meet the standard techniques.

### After working with this db design for product. Here is my table structue:

```
product table
id  product_name product_price  product_desc product_img  groupeid
1   bag red       2000          bag red cool  bag_red.jpg   2
```

So i want to update the product table to:
**option1**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
id productname productprice  productdesc  product_img  product_imgExt groupeid
1  bag red        2000        bag red     bag_red          jpg            2
2  shoes yellow   1000        nice shoes  shoes_yellow     jpg            1
3  Tie yellow   1000          nice Tie    tie_yellow       png            1
```

**option2**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------
img_ext table
id  img_extention
1     jpg
2     png
------------------------------------------------------------------
product table
id  product_name product_price  product_desc product_img  groupeid
1   bag red       2000          bag red cool  bag_red       2
2  Tie yellow   1000            nice Tie      tie_yellow    1    

------------------------------------------------------------------
product_img_table
product_id   img_ext_id
 1             2
 2             1
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

Which option is better to follow: the option 1 or option 2?

Comment: is there any reason to save it separately ?

Comment: @anto.nishanth: as far as i am concerned..No..the file extention should be in the product table..beacuse one product can have only one file extention...So personnally i was thinking about option1...but i want to have some opinion from people with more experience

Answer (score 2):

"Better" is a very subjective judgement.

However, I would suggest you want to separate the understanding of your catalogue (the product table) from the details of how you present that catalogue. The image references you store are effectively links to some other piece of information, but I will bet that as your project evolves, you will need more than one image for each product.

So, my suggestion would be to have a product table with the information about your product, and an images table linking those products to the images. Within the images table, I'd keep it as simple as possible - you're storing a path, and there's no logical reason to separate the suffix from the path. Unless your ecommerce app is also doing some clever image processing, and the file type is significant, I'd just store the full path - the less logic you have, the less code you have to write, and the less opportunity you create for bugs.

So:

Products

```
id  product_name product_price  product_desc   groupeid
1   bag red       2000          bag red cool   2
```

product_images

```
product_id    size_indicator  image_path
1             S               \images\bag_red.jpg 
1             L               \images\bag_red_large.jpg
```

The image_path is exactly that - the path to the image on your hard drive. In your PHP, you'd use that column in the result set to draw an `<img>` tag. If you want to know whether an image is small or large, you look at the column "size_indicator".

Comment: I see what you mean..but your product_images confuse me a bit..you put the small image and big image file extension in the table...when doing the query of the product_images table how can i identify if it is the image small size extension or big size extension.

Comment: I've updated the answer - file extensions are irrelevant in finding out if an image is large or small, and so should the file name be. It's much better to explicitly capture that as an additional column.

Answer (score 0):

I think one! It's better to read and logical for me.

**Edit:**

I would name each column like `product_id`, `product_name`, `groupe_id` and the table names like `PREFIX_products`.